# Why do the results of these two programs don't match/ what is the fault in my logic implementation in the 2nd one?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have two programs in both of which I am evolving the position and momentum of particles with sinusoids.

The difference is that in the first one I update the function at different times and multiply with the same initial conditions while in the second one I keep the function constant due to a constant time step but update the positions and momenta to which they get multiplied.

Both of these trajectories should give exact same results.

Here are the programs:
*Note: The codes are reduced to a minimal reproduction.*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(SP, alf, dt, n):
    "Time"
    counter = 0;
    np.random.seed(0);
    Random=np.random.rand(n-1);
    C=np.array([cos(k*dt) for k in range(0,iter+1)])
    S=np.array([sin(k*dt) for k in range(0,iter+1)])
    for i in range(1, iter + 1):
        t = i * dt;
        Z = [];
        Up = [];
        Down = [];
        c,s=C[i],S[i]
        c1,s1=C[i-1],S[i-1]
        for j in range(n - 1):
            collchk=((c*(SP[j,0])+s*(SP[j,1]))-(c*(SP[j+1,0])+s*(SP[j+1,1])))*(c1*(SP[j,0])+s1*(SP[j,1])-(c1*(SP[j+1,0])+s1*(SP[j+1,1])));
            print(collchk)
    return  counter ,t
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n=5;
    dt=1/(10**(2));
    iter=(4);
    alf=sqrt(n);
    SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([  np.array([i,j,k]) for i, j,k in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial,SPIN)]),
                    key=lambda x: x[0]))
    counter,t = f(SP, alf, dt, n)
    print("Rate of collision per particle = ",(counter/(n*t)))
```

The output:

```
0.03103751937297854
0.08109145781934951
0.22901365345468785
2.5308437990270805
0.03078100154076592
0.08070470111986175
0.2263443458399873
2.538728781711264
0.030519417686482468
0.08030276710131726
0.22364568369773868
2.546117509808945
0.03025287244018221
0.07988581653196439
0.22091874645681717
2.553007027927399
Rate of collision per particle =  0.0
```

and the second one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(SP, SP1,alf, dt, n):
    "Time"
    counter = 0
    np.random.seed(0)
    Random=np.random.rand(n-1)
    c,s=cos(dt),sin(dt)
    for i in range(1, iter + 1):
      
        for j in range(n): 
          SP1[j,0]=SP[j,0]
          SP1[j,1]=SP[j,1]
          SP[j,0]=c*SP[j,0]+s*SP[j,1]
          SP[j,1]=c*SP[j,1]-s*SP[j,0]
        for j in range(n - 1):
            collchk=(SP[j,0]*SP[j+1,0])*(SP1[j,0]*SP[j+1,0])
            print(collchk)
    return counter ,t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n=5;
    dt=1/(10**(2));
    iter=(4);
    alf=sqrt(n);
    Zinitial=[-0.9559708728305755, 1.5751906780581504,-0.014394517940369715, -0.7794354593838172, -0.49433681998221324]
    Pinitial=[0.4066095975477199,0.25889154830799843, -0.0046433361444705125, 0.33541895349394885, 0.270278187797722]
    SPIN=np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
    SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([  np.array([i,j,k]) for i, j,k in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial,SPIN)]),
                    key=lambda x: x[0]))
    SP1= np.array(sorted(np.array([  np.array([i,j,k]) for i, j,k in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial,SPIN)]),
                    key=lambda x: x[0]))
    counter,t = f(SP,SP1, alf, dt, n)
    print("Rate of collision per particle = ",(counter/(n*t)))
    print(t)
```

The output:

```
0.5480084289400645
0.14618603324575455
5.067472238058949e-05
0.0005173929980597125
0.5383898895552246
0.14326676614418565
5.041820847142852e-05
0.0005221806114288456
0.5286869901202106
0.14033507300727344
5.013883366780392e-05
0.0005267892208272126
0.5189082113895205
0.13739341445190348
4.9836908449848145e-05
0.0005312143456136292
Rate of collision per particle =  0.0
0.04
```

Why do the collchks don't match?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: That is why I have printed "collchk." It is not the quantity I finally require in my bigger code

Comment: print ALL variables in ALL places - to see how it works.

Comment: Oh I pasted the same code twice. Please check the edit. There are different variables at some places and the logic used is also different. The same variable is collchk and therefore I checked that.